# Highlighting automatically on file open

Tags: hooks, files, highlighting

I would like to highlight lines with a certain pattern whenever the file is opened.

Specifically when `Journal.org` is opened I want to run commands like `M-s h l` to highlight a set of patterns and assign them background colors.

What is the simplest way to go about doing this (without writing a lot of custom elisp code)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `hi-lock` package has support for saving patterns to a file and re-applying them.

1. Use the standard hi-lock commands to highlight what you are interested in. For example, use `M-s h l` to highlight lines matching some pattern.
2. Use `M-s h w` (`hi-lock-write-interactive-patterns`) to save the current highlight patterns to the file as a special comment line.
3. Enable `hi-lock-mode` or `global-hi-lock-mode`. For example, if you're only using highlighting in org files you could enable hi-lock mode in an org-mode hook.

The next time you visit that file and hi-lock is enabled, you will be prompted whether you want to highlight the found patterns. You can customize `hi-lock-file-patterns-policy` if you don't want to be prompted.

Comment: This is a better solution as it involves less user elisp configuration. I also added `(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'hi-lock-mode)` so I don't have to manually enable that mode (or globally toggle it for all files).

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic case where elisp can help you:

```
(defun my-highlight ()
  (if (string-equal "Journal.org"
                    (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name))
      (highlight-lines-matching-regexp "foo" 'hi-yellow)))

(add-hook 'find-file-hook #'my-highlight)
```

Comment: Thanks! Next I will have to auto-open the last two items in org hierarchy, and I'll be all set...